# Is it good practice to continuously call WaitForSingleObject in while loop?

Tags: multithreading, events, while-loop, waitforsingleobject

I have an **Manual reset event** to control (pause and resume) the while loop. So in the loop, I must continuously check for event signal state

```
void my_loop()
{
    while(is_ok)
    {
        // Check whether event is in signaled state
        dwWaitResult = WaitForSingleObject( 
            ghEvent, // event handle
            INFINITE);    // indefinite wait

        switch (dwWaitResult) 
        {
            // Event object was signaled
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0: 
            printf("my_loop is working");
            break; 

            // An error occurred
        default: 
            printf("my_loop is halted");
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Is this good practice? Does continuously calling `WaitForSingleObject` cause any problem (CPU, memory, ...) ?

Or are there better ways to check for event state in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choosing a **manual resest event** here causes the loop to be busy (100% cpu) while the event is set. So there must another part in your code resetting the event or did you just forget to reset the event at the `WAIT_OBJECT_0` case?

*Is this good practice?* Well, when the event isn't set, this code is just waiting (`INFINITE`). However, when the event is set, this is just busy polling for the event to get reset. 
I suspect you want to do something else in the `WAIT_OBJECT_0` case and you want to have external control. You can do it that way, there is no problem using `WaitForSingleObject`in a loop.

Comment: Yes, other functions can call ResetEvent and SetEvent to toggle the event state, hence causing that loop to pause and resume. Don't worry about what my loop is doing. I just ask whether calling WaitForSingleObject continuously causes any problem (CPU, memory, ...) ?? Or is there any better way to check for event state ?

Comment: As said: _there is no problem using WaitForSingleObjectin a loop_. However, you may also look into [Critical Section Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [Synchronization Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686364%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in general.

Comment: You may also like the idea of external control of the number of loop cycles to go for. For such an approach you should look into [Semaphore Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).